# AJAX request to only load/open a specific div without using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Im looking to do something like this

`$('#thisdiv').load(document.URL +  ' #thisdiv');`

where only the elements with the specified selector are loaded from the server, but I can't use Jquery, anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Have you read the source of `load()`?

Comment: I guess you'r after XMLHttpRequest, which is supported by all modern browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp

Comment: @limelights have you? Recreating [load](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/load.js) from jQuery source would take tons of work, because all the cross-references to other functions/files.

Comment: @maremp Yes, I have. The point was not to copy it straight off but to get the gist of how it works. Just merely copying or asking for a solution is never the wisest choice.

Comment: @limelights I know, but what would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Read the XHR documentation here.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

Basically, you create an XMLHttpRequest object (be wary of older browsers), then trigger its methods to load some content, then take the response and copy it where you want it.

The link above goes on to discuss XML parsing, which may come in handy if you want to use just the "#thisdiv" part of the XHR response.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. At the moment this is what I'm doing, however this is fairly inefficient as the entire page is being requested, which is substantially larger than the div i need. I think i'm going to create a separate file for the div and include it on the page, and then make an XMLHTTPRequest to the div's file.

Comment: "the entire page is being requested, which is substantially larger than the div i need." - If I understand correctly, this is also what jQuery `.load()` does, so don't beat yourself up about it. You're right, your only option here is to separately serve only the part you want.